# Why can I return a reference to a local variable's field

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

[The documentation on ref returns and ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) states:

> The return value must have a lifetime that extends beyond the execution of the method. In other words, it cannot be a local variable in the method that returns it. It can be an instance or static field of a class, or it can be an argument passed to the method. Attempting to return a local variable generates compiler error CS8168, "Cannot return local 'obj' by reference because it is not a ref local."

I thought I understood this. I figured if I returned a reference to a local variable, then that variable might be collected and so my reference no longer references a variable.

However, I learned today that I can create a local variable then return a reference to a field on that local variable. To illustrate:

```csharp
using System;

namespace IAmConfused
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var foo = new Foo();
         ref int barInt = ref foo.GetInt();
         Console.WriteLine(barInt); //Outputs 123

         barInt = 354;
         Console.WriteLine(barInt); //Outputs 354
      }
   }

   public class Foo
   {
      public ref int GetInt()
      {
         // int x = 123;
         // return ref x; //CS8168
         var bar = new Bar(123);
         return ref bar.Value;
      }

      class Bar
      {
         public Bar(int v)
         {
            Value = v;
         }

         public int Value;
      }
   }
}
```

How is this different from just returning a local? The local variable `bar` might be collected after `GetInt` returns, right? So what is `barInt` referencing if that happens?

I've tried `C#` versions 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, and 7.3 and it works on all of them.

Comment: You are not returning the variable `bar`, but something else (`bar.Value`). What happens when you try to return a local variable?

Comment: If I attempt to return a local variable I get a compiler error. CS8168 just as the documentation describes. I'm not sure why returning a field on a local variable should behave differently. It seems like in both cases what I'm returning does not have a lifetime that extends beyond the execution of the method.

Comment: It is not "a field on a local variable", it is "a field from an object, resident in the heap memory". What happens when you try it with a struct instead of a class?

Comment: Changing to a struct also results in CS8168.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this code example:

```
void Foo()
{
    object a;
    int b;
}
```

Both of these variables are held on the stack. Yes, they really are, even the object. The variable `a` is a pointer to the object, not the object itself, and that pointer is indeed a local variable on the stack.

So if you return a reference to either of these, it'll be a reference to some variable that was on the stack. The stack of course is overwritten when the call returns, which is why you can't ref return a local.

On the other hand, consider this example:

```
class Bar
{
    public int SomeInteger;
}

void Foo()
{
    Bar c = new Bar();
}
```

In this case, `c` is held on the stack as well. But the object that it references is on the heap, as is its field, `SomeInteger`. So you can safely return a reference to `SomeInteger` since it exists on the heap and the heap is not overwritten when the method returns.

Comment: The stack isn't overwritten. The stack pointer is moved to reclaim the memory. Great answer otherwise.

Comment: Sure, it's invalidated, I guess, until the next method call, at which point it is overwritten. Think you understand that though.

Comment: Maybe it's overwritten. That depends on what else happens in the program :-)